# Button Click Navigation to DetailView not working in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an UI with few buttons. I want to navigate to detail view on button click. For the first time it navigates successfully but when comeback to root view and again I click on the button, I doesn't navigates.

I have followed all the tutorials and I can see the same code which I have used but I am not getting what is the issue occurring.

State of the variable
`@State var google: Int? = 0` has been defied in view class `struct ContentView: View`

Complete code of the root View

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var username: String = ""
@State var password: String = ""
@State var selection: Int? = nil
@State var google: Int? = 0
@State var buttton1: Int? = nil

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20){

                    Text("Quickly find and book a\n Doctors visit today")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

                    TextField("Email", text: $username)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .accentColor(.white)

                    Divider()

                    TextField("Password", text: $password)
                         .padding(.horizontal)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .accentColor(.white)

                    Divider()

                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), tag: 3, selection: self.$buttton1) {

                        EmptyView();
                    }

                    Button(action:{
                        self.buttton1 = 3;
                        print("Login");
                    }){

                        Text("Sign in")
                            .padding()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }

                    Text("Forgot password?")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            .padding(20)

            HStack {
                VStack { Divider().background(Color.white) }
                Text("or")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                VStack { Divider().background(Color.white) }
            }
            .padding(20)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
                    Button(action:{
                        print("Search and sign up user");
                    }){
                        Text("Search and sign up user")
                            .padding()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .border(Color.white, width: 1)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                    }

                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), tag: 2, selection: self.$google) {
                    Button(action:{
                        self.google = 2;
                        print("Sign in with Google");
                    }){
                        HStack {
                            /*Image(systemName: "")
                                .font(.title)*/
                            Text("Sign in with Google")
                                .padding()
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                    }
                }



                /*NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView()){

                        Text("Click Me")
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }*/

                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {

                    //EmptyView()
                    Button(action:{
                                //self.tag = 1;
                        self.selection = 1;
                                print("Sign in with Apple");

                            },label: {
                                Text("Sign in with Apple")
                            })
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50)
                            .background(Color.black)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            }
                }
                .padding(20)

            }
            .background(Color.blue)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
}

struct ContentView: View {
@State var username: String = ""
@State var password: String = ""
@State var selection: Int? = nil
@State var google: Int? = 0
@State var buttton1: Int? = nil

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20){

                    Text("Quickly find and book a\n Doctors visit today")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

                    TextField("Email", text: $username)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .accentColor(.white)

                    Divider()

                    TextField("Password", text: $password)
                         .padding(.horizontal)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .accentColor(.white)

                    Divider()

                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), tag: 3, selection: self.$buttton1) {

                        EmptyView();
                    }

                    Button(action:{
                        self.buttton1 = 3;
                        print("Login");
                    }){

                        Text("Sign in")
                            .padding()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }

                    Text("Forgot password?")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            .padding(20)

            HStack {
                VStack { Divider().background(Color.white) }
                Text("or")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                VStack { Divider().background(Color.white) }
            }
            .padding(20)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
                    Button(action:{
                        print("Search and sign up user");
                    }){
                        Text("Search and sign up user")
                            .padding()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .border(Color.white, width: 1)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                    }

                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), tag: 2, selection: self.$google) {
                    Button(action:{
                        self.google = 2;
                        print("Sign in with Google");
                    }){
                        HStack {
                            /*Image(systemName: "")
                                .font(.title)*/
                            Text("Sign in with Google")
                                .padding()
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(3)
                        }
                    }
                }



                /*NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView()){

                        Text("Click Me")
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }*/

                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {

                    //EmptyView()
                    Button(action:{
                                //self.tag = 1;
                        self.selection = 1;
                                print("Sign in with Apple");

                            },label: {
                                Text("Sign in with Apple")
                            })
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50)
                            .background(Color.black)
                            .cornerRadius(3)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            }
                }
                .padding(20)

            }
            .background(Color.blue)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

}

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, are you running this issue on Simulator?

Comment: @user1147981: Yes, I am using simulator.

Comment: It is a known bug on Simulator that navigation cannot occurs twice to the same view. For example, in a list, you wouldn't be able to navigate twice into the same row's detail view. Try on real device, it should work!

Comment: i just tested with Version 11.4 (11E146) iOS 13.4 -> works in Simulator

Comment: @AkhilGite Have you tried to update XCode and run the test again? Don't forget to mark answer if it helps ;)

Comment: sure, I will update you.

Answer (score 0):

Known bug on XCode and Simulators with SwiftUI that actually works just fine on real devices. 
You cannot push twice in a row the same view.

For example, let's say you have 3 rows (#1, #2, #3), each with a NavigationLink, you will not be able to push #1, come back and push #1 again.

If you run #1, #2 and then, #1 again, it works.

Again, it is just on Simulator. Try the same code on a real device, it will be good!

Hope this helps!

UPDATE: The bug is fixed in XCode 11.4. You can now navigate multiple times to the same View! Good job Apple ;)